# Please weigh in on this SE Meta question

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295357/287826) relating to the usage of an English phrase on Meta and would appreciate the opinions of ELU folks.  (I'm not sure if I can stop with that, or if I should repeat the question here.  Also I'm not sure if I should ask people to weigh in here or there.)

Comment: The Spanish site has *cómo pedir ayuda* (how to ask for help). The Portuguese site has *Ajuda sobre Perguntas* (help on/for/about questions). Would either of those be an improvement?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that "Asking Help" is a slightly awkward phrase because it *looks like* "asking *for* help," but "Asking for Help" wouldn't convey the same meaning as "Asking Help."

"Asking help" means "Help with asking."  It would be akin to having a sign that said "Writing help" at a literacy center.  In that sense, you can even use it in a sentence.

> I went to the literacy center for **writing help**.
>
> I clicked on the link for **asking help**.

It's also intended to be short and succinct, which "help with asking" is not.

So IMHO, it's probably fine as it is.